# Grouping the common values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, hierarchical-data

I have a table with sample values as below

[image]

In this table, all the values in Col1 will have its supporting values in Col2. The values A1 and A2 are like master values and they will never appear in Col2. I need to make an output displaying this master values in a new column like below

[image]

What would be the best way to achieve this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a hierarchical query:

```
SQL> select connect_by_root t.col1 as main,
  2         t.col1,
  3         t.col2
  4  from test t
  5  start with t.col1 in ('A1', 'A2')
  6  connect by t.col1 = prior t.col2
  7  order by main, t.col1, t.col2;

MAIN  COL1  COL2
----- ----- -----
A1    A1    B1
A1    A1    B2
A1    A1    B3
A1    B1    C1
A1    B2    C2
A1    C1    D1
A2    A2    E1
A2    A2    E2
A2    E1    F1
A2    E1    F2

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```